# Jena Reasoner does not follow inferred statements when executing SPARQL queries

Tags: java, sparql, jena, ontology, semantic-web

I have been learning about Semantic Web recently and testing stuff with Jena. I have a model with 2 Ontologies and 2 sets of Instance data. One Ontology is actually FOAF (Friend-of-a-Friend), and the other also represents people. I tried adding statements to align these two Ontologies and the statements seem to have effect - after adding them to the model and printing statements about them from the model, I can see that they are added. However, when I perform SPARQL query, it does not seem to take them into account.

For the sake of simplicity, I will just write the main points in the code.

I am performing the following SPARQL query on a FOAF ontology, where `swp2:me` is an instance in my instance data:

```
select distinct ?name where {
    swp2:me foaf:knows ?friend .
    ?friend foaf:name ?name .
}
```

The above query properly grabs all the friends of `swp2:me` resource. Next, I have another custom Ontology in this model (putting both Ontology and instance data below):

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont> rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
                                                         owl:versionIRI <http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont/1.0.0> .

:hasFriend rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                    owl:SymmetricProperty .

:hasName rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .

:Individual rdf:type owl:Class .

:Individual_5 rdf:type :Individual ;
              :hasFriend :Individual_6 ,
                         :Individual_7 ;
              :hasName "Sem Web" .

:Individual_6 rdf:type :Individual ;
              :hasFriend :Individual_5 ;
              :hasName "Web O. Data" .

:Individual_7 rdf:type :Individual ;
              :hasFriend :Individual_5 ;
              :hasName "Mr. Owl" .
```

Now, I try to align these two Ontologies, as well as express that `swp2:me` (instance from first Ontology) and `:Individual_5` (that is, instance from second Ontology) are the same instance. I do this using the following method in Java:

```
private void alignTwoOntologies()
    {
        System.out.println("Aligning People and FOAF Ontologies...");
        
        Resource resource;
        Property prop;
        Resource obj;
        
        resource = friendsModel.createResource(personNamespace + "Individual");
        prop = friendsModel.createProperty("owl:equivalentClass");
        obj = friendsModel.createResource("foaf:Person");
        friendsModel.add(resource, prop, obj);
        
        resource = friendsModel.createResource(personNamespace + "hasName");
        prop = friendsModel.createProperty("owl:equivalentProperty");
        obj = friendsModel.createResource("foaf:name");
        friendsModel.add(resource, prop, obj);
        
        resource = friendsModel.createResource(personNamespace + "hasFriend");
        prop = friendsModel.createProperty("rdfs:subPropertyOf");
        obj = friendsModel.createResource("foaf:knows");
        friendsModel.add(resource, prop, obj);
        
        resource = friendsModel.createResource(defaultNamespace + "me");
        prop = friendsModel.createProperty("owl:sameAs");
        obj = friendsModel.createResource(personNamespace + "Individual_5");
        friendsModel.add(resource, prop, obj);
    }
```

The model seems to be affected properly - when I open the resulting model in Protege, I can see, for example, on `swp2:me` instance that it has `owl:sameAs Individual_5`. Same stands for Classes and Properties that are aligned.
**However, when I execute the same query that I stated at the start, it does not pick up additional friends (Individual_6, Individual_7) of Individual_5 (which is same as `swp2:me` instance) and I expect it to pick them up.**
Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Placing the full code for reference:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.OWL;

public class HelloSemanticWeb {

    static String defaultNamespace = "http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#";
    static String personNamespace = "http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont#";
    Model friendsModel = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HelloSemanticWeb hello = new HelloSemanticWeb();

        // Initialize model
        hello.friendsModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF);
        
        // Instance data
        hello.populateInstanceData();
        
        // Populate Schemas
        hello.populateSchemas();
        
        // Align ontologies
        hello.alignTwoOntologies();
        
        // Print friends
        hello.myFriends(hello.friendsModel);
    }
    
    private void populateInstanceData() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // FOAF Friends
        this.friendsModel.read(new FileInputStream("Ontologies/FOAFFriends_turtle.ttl"), null, "TTL");
        
        // People ontology instances
        this.friendsModel.read(new FileInputStream("Ontologies/additionalFriends.owl"), null, "TTL");
    }
    
    private void populateSchemas() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // FOAF Schema
        this.friendsModel.read("http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/index.rdf");
        
        // People Schema
        this.friendsModel.read(new FileInputStream("Ontologies/additionalFriendsSchema.owl"), null, "TTL");
    }
    
    private void myFriends(Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("\n-- Say hello to my friends-- ");
        runQuery("select distinct ?name where {"
                + "swp2:me foaf:knows ?friend ."
                + "?friend foaf:name ?name ."
                + "}", model);
    }
    
    private void runQuery(String queryRequest, Model model)
    {
        StringBuffer queryStr = new StringBuffer();
        
        // Prefixes
        queryStr.append("PREFIX swp2: <" + defaultNamespace + "> ");
        queryStr.append("PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> ");
        
        // Query
        queryStr.append(queryRequest);
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr.toString());
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        
        try 
        {
            ResultSet response = qexec.execSelect();
            boolean hasFriends = response.hasNext();
            
            while(response.hasNext())
            {
                QuerySolution soln = response.nextSolution();
                RDFNode name = soln.get("?name");
                if(name != null)
                    System.out.println("Hello to " + name.toString());
            }
            
            if(!hasFriends)
                System.out.println("No Friends found!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error executing query: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            qexec.close();
        }
    }
    
    private void alignTwoOntologies()
    {
        System.out.println("Aligning People and FOAF Ontologies...");
        
        Resource resource;
        Property prop;
        Resource obj;
        
        resource = friendsModel.createResource(personNamespace + "Individual");
        prop = OWL.equivalentClass; //friendsModel.createProperty("owl:equivalentClass");
        obj = friendsModel.createResource("foaf:Person");
        friendsModel.add(resource, prop, obj);
        
        resource = friendsModel.createResource(personNamespace + "hasName");
        prop = OWL.equivalentProperty; //friendsModel.createProperty("owl:equivalentProperty");
        obj = friendsModel.createResource("foaf:name");
        friendsModel.add(resource, prop, obj);
        
        resource = friendsModel.createResource(personNamespace + "hasFriend");
        prop = OWL.equivalentProperty; //friendsModel.createProperty("rdfs:subPropertyOf");
        obj = friendsModel.createResource("foaf:knows");
        friendsModel.add(resource, prop, obj);
        
        resource = friendsModel.createResource(defaultNamespace + "me");
        prop = OWL.sameAs; //friendsModel.createProperty("owl:sameAs");
        obj = friendsModel.createResource(personNamespace + "Individual_5");
        friendsModel.add(resource, prop, obj);
    }
}
```

File `FOAFFriends_turtle.ttl`:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix admin: <http://webns.net/mvcb/> .
@prefix owl: <http://w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix swp2: <http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#> .

swp2:me
    rdf:type foaf:Person ;
    foaf:depiction <http://semwebprogramming.org/semweb.jpg> ;
    foaf:family_name "Web" ;
    foaf:givenname "Semantic" ;
    foaf:homepage <http://semwebprogramming.org> ;
    foaf:knows swp2:Reasoner , swp2:Statement , swp2:Ontology ;
    foaf:name "Semantic Web" ;
    foaf:nick "Webby" ;
    foaf:phone <tel:410-679-8999> ;
    foaf:schoolHomepage <http://www.web.edu> ;
    foaf:title "Dr" ;
    foaf:workInfoHomepage <http://semwebprogramming.com/dataweb.html> ;
    foaf:workplaceHomepage <http://semwebprogramming.com> .
    
swp2:Reasoner
    rdf:type foaf:Person ;
    rdfs:seeAlso <http://reasoner.com> ;
    foaf:mbox <mailto:reason@hotmail.com> ;
    foaf:name "Ican Reason" .
    
swp2:Statement
    rdf:type foaf:Person ;
    rdfs:seeAlso <http://statement.com> ;
    foaf:mbox <mailto:mstatement@gmail.com> ;
    foaf:name "Makea Statement" .
    
swp2:Ontology
    rdf:type foaf:Person ;
    rdfs:seeAlso <http://ont.com> ;
    foaf:mbox <mailto:ont@gmail.com> ;
    foaf:name "I. M. Ontology" .
```

File `additionalFriends.owl`:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont> .

:Individual_5 rdf:type :Individual ;
              :hasFriend :Individual_6 ,
                         :Individual_7 ;
              :hasName "Sem Web" .

:Individual_6 rdf:type :Individual ;
              :hasFriend :Individual_5 ;
              :hasName "Web O. Data" .

:Individual_7 rdf:type :Individual ;
              :hasFriend :Individual_5 ;
              :hasName "Mr. Owl" .
```

File `additionalFriendsSchema.owl`:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont> rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
                                                         owl:versionIRI <http://www.semanticweb.org/luka/ontologies/2022/0/ont/1.0.0> .

:hasFriend rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                    owl:SymmetricProperty .

:hasName rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .

:Individual rdf:type owl:Class .
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost with your description - where do you run the query on which dataset? Are you suing Jena to execute the query? If so, how? Please show the source code.

Comment: also, are you sure this works: `friendsModel.createProperty("owl:equivalentClass");`? - `createProperty` expects a URI as argument. Why aren't you using the Jena built-in classes for `OWL` ? https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/vocabulary/OWL.html

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for your comment, I tried replacing the `createProperty` calls with built-in classes but it didn't work either. I edited my post and placed full code, along with turtle files.

Comment: you still have issues with your URIs, e.g. `friendsModel.createResource("foaf:name");` results in `<foaf:name>` - you always have to use full URIs. For FOAF there is also a built-in vocab class, use `FOAF.Person`, `FOAF.name` and `FOAF.knows` instead. Or write the full URIs as string - but not prefixed URIs as string. Jena doesn't resolve those when creating the resources. Fixing that issue makes your code return `Hello to Ican Reason
Hello to Makea Statement
Hello to I. M. Ontology
Hello to Mr. Owl
Hello to Web O. Data`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks a lot! This was the exact problem, I was not aware that I cannot use prefixed URIs. You can post an answer so that I can accept it. I appreciate the help!